# Running multiple services on one Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, nas, mail-server, owncloud-server, nextcloud

I have 2 PC's - 1 i am running pfsense and will be a dedicated machine for that purpose(unless i can run it all on one).

2nd machine i have i was thinking of putting Mail Server, NAS, and Nexcloud/Owncloud and off-course this comes with a data base as well for storing and managing Mail server and Cloud data. May be in the future will add one or two more services like ruTorrent or may be Plex Server.

Is it possible to run all of these on one Ubuntu server with 1 IP from LAN which off-course will be forwarded at the router level for remote access, but separate ports for each service or would it be better to virtualize with VMWare or Virtual box or similar service? How stable would this be?

Comment: You Can do this all in One computer. but i think you will need to VM the pfsense server.

Comment: Sounds good! Yeah I would prefer to leave pfsense separate machine and would probably want to run all the other services mentioned on 1 machine without having to virtualization

Answer (score 0):

There are dedicated Linux Distributions for Virtualization. For example Proxmox which is Debian based and it includes an Web Interface for easy management.

I am using it for running and Owncloud and a lot of other different services at home and also in production: https://www.proxmox.com/en/

Comment: Thanks! Interested in doing the mail server option proxmox offer as well since I will be doing mail server along with NAs and other services although I like the idea and possibly can do virtualization was looking for more of running it all on one with different ports but with one single Lan IP